# The range of $a$ for which $f(x)= ax + \cos(2x) + \sin(x) + \cos(x)$ is strictly increasing.

Tags: calculus

I have tried to solve this using the fact that the derivative of $f(x)$ should be greater than zero. But I couldn't proceed after that.

Answer (score 5):

$a - 2\sin 2x + \cos x - \sin x > 0\\
a>  2\sin 2x - \cos x + \sin x$

Lets manipulate the RHS to get something easier to work with.

$ 2\sin 2x - \cos x + \sin x\\
4\sin x\cos x - \cos x + \sin x\\
 -2(\cos x - \sin x)^2 + 2(\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x) - (\cos x - \sin x)\\
 -2(\cos x - \sin x)^2 - (\cos x - \sin x)+2$

Let $u = \cos x - \sin x$

The range of $u$ is bounded

maximize $-2u^2 + u + 2$ over the interval $[-\sqrt2, \sqrt 2]$

The max is at $u = \frac 14$ and $-2u^2 + u + 2 = \frac {17}{8}$

The min is at one of the end points, but we don't care about that.

Comment: Ok. I have understood this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the range of $a$ where $f(x)$ is strictly increasing for all $x$?

If so, from the derivative, you see the requirement for $f^{\prime}(x)>0$ is exactly that
$a>2\sin(2x)-\cos(x)+\sin(x)$. Since this holds for all $x$, you just need to find the maximum of $2\sin(2x)-\cos(x)+\sin(x)$. MAPLE gave the upper bound of 17/8, but I did not check any of this by hand.

Comment: Yeah that's the correct answer but I cannot understand how the max value of 2sin2x - cosx + sinx is 17/8. I tried to find the max value graphically and it came 2-(2)^1/2

Answer (score 0):

Doug M provided a nice and simple solution.

*More complex but doable*

You are looking for the maximum value of $$2\sin(2x)-\cos(x)+\sin(x)$$ Using the tangent half-angle substitution, this is the same as finding the maximum of
$$f(t)=\frac{t^4-6 t^3+10 t-1}{\left(t^2+1\right)^2}$$ and we have
$$f'(t)=\frac{6 t^4+4 t^3-48 t^2+4 t+10 }{\left(t^2+1\right)^3}=\frac{2 \left(t^2-2 t-1\right) \left(3 t^2+8 t-5\right)}{\left(t^2+1\right)^3}$$
So, the first derivative cancels at
$$t_1=1+\sqrt{2}\qquad t_2=1-\sqrt{2}\qquad t_3=-\frac{1}{3} \left(4+\sqrt{31}\right)\qquad t_4=-\frac{1}{3} \left(4-\sqrt{31}\right)$$
We have
$$f''(t)=-4\frac{ 3 t^5+3 t^4-54 t^3+2 t^2+39 t-1}{\left(t^2+1\right)^4}$$ and so
$$f''(t_1)=14-\frac{19}{\sqrt{2}} >0 \qquad f''(t_2)= 14+\frac{19}{\sqrt{2}} >0$$
$$f''(t_3)=\frac{31}{128} \left(7 \sqrt{31}-40\right) <0 \qquad f''(t_4)= -\frac{31}{128} \left(7 \sqrt{31}+40\right)<0$$ So, the maximum corresponds (by the second derivative test) to $t_3$ or $t_4$.

$$f(t_3)=f(t_4)=\frac{17}{8}$$